# how to remove unneccesary files already committed before git push

Tags: git

Let me explain the issue here :-

1) I created a new branch :

`git checkout -b <newbranch>`

2) I modified file1.tcl in this branch and committed it (no push done till now)

3) Now i had to work on another 2 separate files and i should have created a separate branch for it but mistakenly i started working on the same `<newbranch>` and committed both that files too (file2.tcl and file3.tcl) from this same branch

4) so realising my mistake at this point I created a new separate branch  and did my changes (they were few only) to file2.tcl and file3.tcl from here and committed them and even did a git push. so now the required changes for file2.tcl and file3.tcl are in place and pushed to github

5) Now coming back to `<newbranch>` , As I want to push the changes done in file1.tcl from here , the problem is I can see that if i push now along with file1.tcl ...file2.tcl and file3.tcl will also go in PUSH. So I somehow want to take those 2 files out of my git-push stack

```
gourabm@lb4b13-pc-01(eRx)$ git diff --stat --cached origin/master
 eRx/lib/file1.tcl | 3348       +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 eRx/bin/file2.tcl |    1 -
 eRx/lib/file3.tcl |   75 +++---
 3 files changed, 1978 insertions(+), 1446 deletions(-)
```

Please suggest me an easy and safe way to take these 2 files out of my git-push list so that they dont go in the push and only one file1.tcl goes in the push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried

```
git revert {commit-that-changed-file2.tcl}
git revert {commit-that-changed-file3.tcl}
git commit -m "undoing extra changes"
```

from my understanding git should undo the changes in just those commits and allow you to re-commit with those changes before push, so your remote should remain unaffected.

Comment: worst case, manually 'un-change' the files and commit them again

Answer (score 1):

`git reset --hard HEAD^1` in your **newbranch** would remove the commit which had changes in file2.tcl and file3.tcl. Now

1. your  would have a commit with changes in file1.tcl and
2. the second branch would have a commit with changes in the other two files.